# For a IONIC project change .apk name

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

While building ionic app, by default ionic is creating `platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk` file. How can i change the name of generated `.apk` file?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update the following files:

YourProjectName/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml
YourProjectName/platforms/android/build.xml
YourProjectName/platforms/android/src/com/yourpackagename/appfolder/CordovaApp.java

NOTE: From the above (file 3), com/yourpackagename/appfolder will correspond to the reverse domain name you used when when set up your application.

STEP 1
Got to the AndroidManifest.xml file and look for:

```
<activity android:configchanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchmode="singleTop" android:name="CordovaApp" android:screenorientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowsoftinputmode="adjustResize">
```

Change CordovaApp in android:name="CordovaApp" to whatever the name of your project is 
(android:name="testApp").

STEP 2:
In the build.xml file locate the following line:

Change CordovaApp to the name of your project and should match the one in put in step 1 (i.e 
name="testApp").

STEP 3
This stage is abit more tricky and extra caution should be taken when doing this, or else you 
might mess things up big time...and that is not Awesome!!

Locate the file Cordova.java and rename it to project name (Same as
step 1 and 2...i.e testApp.java).

Open the renamed file and locate the line :
public class CordovaApp extends CordovaActivity change it to the project name like:
public class testApp extends CordovaActivity

.....That's it!!!

Run the command : ionic build android --release

This should result in:

```
Built the following apk(s):
    /Path-to-your-project/platforms/android/ant-build/testApp-release-unsigned.apk
```

Comment: i cant ... mine is ionic4 ... my default name of apk is app-debug.apk and i have     <target name="cordova_debug" depends="debug">
    </target>